# Stack level too deep trying to update from 3.0 to 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting this error while trying to run 'rails s' after upgrading update from rails 3.0.10 to 3.1.0

> ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/builder.rb:40: stack level too deep 
>   (SystemStackError)

Has anyone else run into this and solved the problem? Google search yields nothing except that it might involve gem dependencies.

Comment: It maybe an error in the code. Can you try 'bundle exec rails s' to see what happens.

Comment: 'bundle exec rails s' gives the same exact thing. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: I am also getting the same error :( .

Comment: @vikram I still haven't been able to solve this. Let me know if you find anything.

Comment: for me the issue was in a plugin...i removed that and it disappeared :)